# Wordpress removes URL parameters from menu elements when saving the menu

Tags: menus, links

I'm trying to add some submenu elements to interact with a shortcode in my page. The shortcode is a tabbed group and the following URL opens a specific tab:

```
https://wp1.samuelezappala.it/?tab=prestito-e-raccolta-libri
```

So I obtain this setting:

[image] [image]

The problem is that I need to also append an anchor to the URL, because I need the page to scroll to the right section. I cannot append it before the query vars because the system that opens the right tab wouldn't work (people confirm it [here](https://themenectar.ticksy.com/ticket/897729/)). I need to append the anchor at the end of the URL, like this:

```
https://wp1.samuelezappala.it/?tab=prestito-e-raccolta-libri#servizi
```

In the menu editor I save the custom link with the query vars, but in the actual website they are removed:

[image: Menu editor]

[image: Actual link in the website]

---

I tried solving appending the query vars, but I need to also append the anchor at the end. I used the following code, taken from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731750/wordpress-how-can-i-add-url-get-parameter-to-my-main-menu-items) question:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3 );


function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args ){
    if( is_admin() ){
        return $items;
    }else{
    foreach( $items as $item ) 
    {
        if( 'Prestito e raccolta libri' == $item->post_title){
            $item->url .= '?tab=prestito-e-raccolta-libri';
            //$item->url .= '#servizi';
        }
    }
    return $items;
    }
}
```

But again, it seems that if there's an anchor in the URL, every query var gets stripped away:
[image]

Comment: are you saying you can have an anchor, and you can have URL parameters, but you can't have _both_ at the same time? Also are you sure there are no trailing spaces on the menu title? I see you added the `nav_items` function but there is no `add_action` or `add_filter` call, it's not enough to add a function, you have to use it, and there's also a PHP syntax mistake you made that would be obvious if it was indented correctly, there are no curly braces after the if statement, so only the first line counts

Comment: I corrected the code: I forgot to paste the first line; I added the curly braces, but still nothing.
It seems that I cannot have both, but more precisely only the URL parameters get removed.

Comment: The code is indented properly: if I don't append "#servizi", the line before works and appends the URL parameters.